# Can I stop browser extensions from overriding my site's css?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently playing around with a personal website. However I noticed that the glyphs on the site, for which I have a dedicated font, weren't showing properly on Chrome. I quickly found that an extension, Chromoji, was injecting css rules that were replacing my glyphs with a sprite.

Is there a tag or something I can add to my site to stop style injection? Or a way to make my styles take precedent?

Comment: More-specific selectors? A Content Security Policy maybe? In general, a client can do whatever it wants though.

Comment: I think I'll just have to replace the glyphs with my own sprites, since then they wont be interpreted as emojis.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara CSP specifically doesn't block browser extensions.

Comment: Why are there two votes to move to Super User? Since when did HTML/CSS questions belong there?

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: don't use glyph fonts. Use SVG icons instead :)

Something like...

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <use xlink:href="icons.svg#iconID" />
</svg>
```

`icons.svg` would be an SVG file containing various icons, each icon having an `id` attribute which you can reference in the `<use>` tag.

SVGs are [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) and I've been using them to great effect on my own projects.

Comment: I opted for sprites instead, as it's more in-keeping with what I've done elsewhere in the site.